# I am using Darwin OS on terminal but cannot use apt-get, yum command(only brew is usable)

Tags: mac, terminal, apt-get, darwin

I am using terminal on Darwin OS but cannot use `apt-get` and `yum` commands (only `brew` is usable).

Sometime, I need to use `apt-get` (ex. to install linux essential header)

But my terminal says `command not found`

So what should I do for it?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of an open source package you want to install on Darwin that isn't available via Homebrew? You might be thinking of Linux-specific things that don't run on Darwin (which is a BSD-based Unix, not Linux).

Answer (score 2):

Darwin is Apple's own BSD-derived Unix, not Linux. You have to use open source package managers meant for Darwin/macOS such as Homebrew or MacPorts. If Homebrew and MacPorts don't contain a port of an open source software package you care about, it's possible that no one is maintaining a Darwin port of that package and you'll need to download that package yourself and figure out for yourself how to get it to compile and run in Darwin (i.e. port it yourself).